# How do I count something the number of employee that is in a different table in SQL?

Tags: sql

The question asks

"Write a query to display the city and country where an office is located and a count of the number of employees at that location. Order the results in descending order of the number of employees."

So far I have put,

```
SELECT city, country, SELECT COUNT(city,country) 
FROM Offices
ORDER BY(SELECT COUNT(city,country) 
                FROM Offices)DESC;
```

It wont let me run it however. I reckon I made a mistake in the SELECT COUNT part.

The employees table contains

- employeeNumber
- lastName
- firstName
- extension
- email
- reportsTo
- jobTitle
- officeCode

The Office table contains

- officeCode
- city
- phone
- addressLine1
- addressLine2
- state
- country
- postalCode
- territory
- officeLocation

Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly? Thank you! Sorry if this is a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do it using a LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and ORDER BY.
We need LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY to get the employee count and the ORDER BY to order the results in descending order of no of employees.

SELECT OfficeCode, City, Country, COUNT(E.employeeNumber) AS EmployeeCount
FROM Offices O
LEFT JOIN Employees E ON E.OfficeCode = E.OfficeCode
GROUP BY OfficeCode, City, Country
ORDER BY COUNT(E.employeeNumber) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use join and count

```
SELECT city, country,officeLocation, COUNT(e.employeeNumber) 
FROM Offices ofc join employees e on ofc.officeCode=e.officeCode
group by city, country,officeLocation
```

Comment: why do you say 'ofc' and 'e'?

Comment: @Bhylee those are aliases to allow a shorthand reference to a table or view

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Is there any other way you could write it?

Comment: @Bhylee Not sure exactly what you mean. If you are asking can different aliases be used, the answer is yes. You define the alias by referencing the table or view and then place an alias name after the object.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways to tackle this. Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN: (make sure to use a  LEFT OUTER and not an INNER JOIN here or else you will only get locations with employees. That may work in your case but what if a location has no current employees?)

```
SELECT City, Country, COUNT(e.employeeNumber) AS EmployeeCount
FROM Offices o
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees e
    ON e.OfficeCode = o.OfficeCode
GROUP BY City, Country
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Or you could use a subquery with the select statement:

```
SELECT City, Country,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees e WHERE o.OfficeCode = e.OfficeCode) AS EmployeeCount
FROM Offices o
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: I'm confused on the single 'e' and 'o', are those completely necessary? How else could you write that?

Comment: The 'e' and the 'o' are not necessary at all. I simply renamed the table "Offices" in my query with 'o'. (this is known as an alias, I did the same thing with "Employees" by using an 'e') As you can see later in the query, with my join, I used that alias to join them. I could have easily left them as just offices and employees like you have spelled out in your question, but then I would have to write out the whole name of them when I did that join. This saved a few keystrokes.